# What happens if you send BTC to a testnet address?

Tags: testnet

What happens if you send real Bitcoins to a testnet address?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. The version byte for testnet addresses is different, so their addresses start with "m" or "n" rather than a 1 for the real network. A client will see the address as invalid.